# Django MPTT's template tags destroying HTML markup

Tags: django, templates, escaping, django-mptt

I'm using Django MPTT to handle my hierarchical Data in my Django application. I'd like to render a TreeView using the `recursetree` tag. However, with this code :

```
{% recursetree system_list %}
    <li>{{ node.title }}
        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
            <ul>
                {{ children.title }}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```

I get such a markup :

```
              <li>Uppeur kar parK

            <ul>

    &lt;Li&gt;Caillou

            &lt;Ul&gt;

    &amp;Lt;Li&amp;Gt;Patate

    &amp;Lt;/Li&amp;Gt;

    &amp;Lt;Li&amp;Gt;Courgette

    &amp;Lt;/Li&amp;Gt;

    &amp;Lt;Li&amp;Gt;Artichaud

    &amp;Lt;/Li&amp;Gt;

    &amp;Lt;Li&amp;Gt;Brocoli

    &amp;Lt;/Li&amp;Gt;

            &lt;/Ul&gt;

    &lt;/Li&gt;

    &lt;Li&gt;Pierre

    &lt;/Li&gt;

            </ul>

    </li>
```

Do you know why the markup is escaped after the second level ? How could I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{{ children }}` instead of `{{ children.title }}`.